# How CancelInvoke() works in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I thought a lot about phrasing the heading of this thread but somehow ended up with a dumb question.

What I want to do :

I want to refactor my code so that I can replace all Invoke(string,seconds) calls in unity with my own method(Routine) `IEnumerator WaitAndExecute(float time, Action callback)` which waits for "time" seconds and executes the "callback".

Reason : I don't want to pass methods as strings as it makes it difficult to find references in IDE.

Problem : My CancelInvoke() doesn't work on methods that were executed without Invoke().

So I want to know how unity keeps tracks of things and references of invoked methods to later cancel them.

Comment: Instead of using `Invoke` and `CancelInvoke` you can use `StartCoroutine` and `StopCoroutine` where `StopCoroutine` does not only accepts string as a parameter but also a function of `IEnumerator` type.

Comment: But won't it stop all the ongoing co-routines as well, where as CancelInvoke() only preempts the calls that are still to occur..can you confirm?

Comment: @RafalWiliński is right, you mean StopAllCoroutines(). This method stops everything (INSIDE THAT SCRIPT). However, StopCoroutine(name or function) stops only the first of that specific function.

Answer (score 1):

The following is just assumption.

Most likely, when you call Invoke(string, float); Unity adds a dictionary entry of type string, object. This allows to run any signature. On the other hand, more generic makes less precision.

The string is probably used for reflection on the object to see if the method can be added:

```
MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
if(mi != null){
    // Create Delegate
    // Add to dictionary or other collection
}
```

Each frame, it iterates all entries and run them if the timing is done. Then removes the entry.

When you call CancelInvoke(string); it checks if the entry exists and removes it.

If you want to deal with coroutine, you may want to use:

```
IEnumerator coroutine = null;
IEnumerator MyCoroutine(){ yield return null; }

void Start(){
    coroutine = MyCoroutine();
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    coroutine = null;
}
```

Note that the internal functioning of that pattern is most likely similar to the Invoke with a collection of IEnumerator pending to be run.

Comment: can you please give some references to prove your explanation?

Comment: No since there is none. Unity does not expose the internal functioning of their engine so for a question that cannot be answered, only assumption is possible, until some unity dev chimes in and drops the exact solution. The second part is accurate though.

Comment: My assumption is more to give a possible understanding so the OP may fix his issue.

Comment: Yes it might be a good assumption as you can see how call back methods are implemented: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/

Comment: Well, the string is probably used for reflection to find the method on the object. But Update works at compile time so it is a bit irrelevant. I'll add the reflection part to help the OP further.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have understood from your question :
you have some invokes and some coroutines in your code.

Previously before refactoring you have had to call CancelInvoke() but for now you should pair any CancelInvoke() with StopAllCoroutines() on any MonoBehaviour.

Also another thing to mention is that your method

```
IEnumerator WaitAndExecute(float time, Action callback)
```

is not a good one, you should also pass MonoBehaviour to start coroutine exactly on the object that want to run Callback. for example :

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

void Start()
{

    Utils.WaitAndExecute(this , 5, callback);
}

public void callback()
{
    // blah blah blah
}

}

public class Utils
{
public void WaitAndExecute(MonoBehaviour objectToRun , float time, Action callback)
{
    // ...
    objectToRun.StartCoroutine(...);
    // ...
}
}
```

This way you can easily stop coroutines inside Player script:

```
StopAllCoroutines();
```

Comment: But won't it stop all the ongoing co-routines as well, where as CancelInvoke() only preempts the calls that are still to occur.

Comment: @Jajan yes, this method stops all coroutines.